# VSCode - find and replace with regexp, but keep word

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I have multiple occurance of `src={icons.ICON_NAME_HERE}` in my code, that I would like to change to `name="ICON_NAME_HERE"`.

Is it possible to do it with regular expressions, so I can keep whatever is in code as `ICON_NAME_HERE`?

To clarify:

I have for example `src={icons.upload}` and `src={icons.download}`, I want to do replace all with one regexp, so those gets converted to `name="upload"` and `name="download"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try searching on the following pattern:

```
src=\{icons\.([^}]+)\}
```

And then replace with your replacement:

```
name="$1"
```

In case you are wondering, the quantity in parentheses in the search pattern is *captured* during the regex search.  Then, we can access that captured group using `$1` in the replacement.  In this case, the captured group should just be the name of the icon.

Comment: Mr. Tim. Thank you very much! I knew it was possible, but some regexps are just to much for me :) And now when I'm writing this comment you keep editing yours so I can better understand it. That's brilliant!